# Geom_Contour error: Contour requires single `z` at each combination of `x` and `y`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset of zipcodes in the United States and a third variable for each zip code. I am trying to use `geom_contour` to map the density of the "Z" variable.

I made a scatter plot on top of a map of the United States and added density contours based on the points, but I want the density plot to be based on the "Z" values of each point instead of the concentration of just the points.

I made a base plot of just the scatter plot using the following code:

```
eastplot <- ggplot(east_data,aes(longitude,latitude)) +
geom_polygon(data=us,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),color='gray',fill=NA,alpha=.35)+
  geom_point(aes(color = GrossProfit),size=.5,alpha=.25) +
  xlim(-95,-65)+ylim(23,50) +
  coord_fixed(1.3)
```

The below code creates a map similar to one I am trying to make, except the below code shows the densities of each point and not the density of the "Z" values

```
eastplot + geom_density2d() + 
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size = 0.01, bins = 5, geom = 'polygon')
```

I tried to make a map with the densities of my "Z" variable, but I am getting an error:

> "Contour requires single `z` at each combination of `x` and `y`."
>
> eastplot + geom_contour(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, z=GrossProfit), stat='contour')

I tried to complete the dataset and adding a zero value for all new values but this created such a large dataset that my R studio stopped responding.

edit: the output of dput(head(east_data, 20)) is

````
"01028", "01038", "01060", "01061", "01082", "01085", "01093", 
"01104", "01105", "01119", "01201", "01237", "01247", "01257", 
"01301"), GrossProfit = c(2450.71, 754.92, 2015.9, 450.91, 9125.165, 
1665.24, 726.35, 106.81, 757.2, 116, 1361.72, 5.49, 556.07, 724.5, 
2056.68, 5594.89, 2960.68, 5473.02, 2451.05, 466.11), city = c("Amherst", 
"Brimfield", "Chicopee", "Cummington", "Easthampton", "East Longmeadow", 
"Hatfield", "Northampton", "Northampton", "Ware", "Westfield", 
"Whately", "Springfield", "Springfield", "Springfield", "Pittsfield", 
"Lanesboro", "North Adams", "Sheffield", "Greenfield"), state = c("MA", 
"MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", 
"MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA"), latitude = c(42.377651, 
42.126038, 42.161492, 42.465041, 42.27279, 42.066795, 42.375155, 
42.324539, 42.369562, 42.270611, 42.133642, 42.442673, 42.130343, 
42.096644, 42.128442, 42.45384, 42.557346, 42.696064, 42.102694, 
42.605524), longitude = c(-72.50323, -72.20552, -72.60316, -72.91813, 
-72.68677, -72.5102, -72.60832, -72.63561, -72.63599, -72.26067, 
-72.75029, -72.652511, -72.57338, -72.5798, -72.50932, -73.254, 
-73.24364, -73.10145, -73.36591, -72.60098)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: How is `east_data` structured? Are the lat/long pairs polygon outlines of each ZIP code, or the point center of each ZIP code?

Comment: Hi Brian. east_data is three columns: latitude, longitude, and the "Z" variable. I created a scatterplot with the lat/long as the x and y axis. I completed the dataset with the complete function and assigned zero to all new pairs of x and y. I am no longer getting the error but geom_contour is not working, I am just getting a scatterplot with points at each x and y combination.

Comment: Can you share `dput(head(east_data, 20))`?

Comment: For sure, here is the output. I need to split it into three comments due to character limits. 1/3 structure(list(zip = c("01002", "01010", "01013", "01026", "01027", 
"01028", "01038", "01060", "01061", "01082", "01085", "01093", 
"01104", "01105", "01119", "01201", "01237", "01247", "01257", 
"01301"), GrossProfit = c(2450.71, 754.92, 2015.9, 450.91, 9125.165, 
1665.24, 726.35, 106.81, 757.2, 116, 1361.72, 5.49, 556.07, 724.5, 
2056.68, 5594.89, 2960.68, 5473.02, 2451.05, 466.11), city = c("Amherst", 
"Brimfield", "Chicopee", "Cummington", "Easthampton", "East Longmeadow",

Comment: (2/3) "Hatfield", "Northampton", "Northampton", "Ware", "Westfield", 
"Whately", "Springfield", "Springfield", "Springfield", "Pittsfield", 
"Lanesboro", "North Adams", "Sheffield", "Greenfield"), state = c("MA", 
"MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", 
"MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MA"), latitude = c(42.377651, 
42.126038, 42.161492, 42.465041, 42.27279, 42.066795, 42.375155, 
42.324539, 42.369562, 42.270611, 42.133642, 42.442673, 42.130343,

Comment: (3/3) 42.096644, 42.128442, 42.45384, 42.557346, 42.696064, 42.102694, 
42.605524), longitude = c(-72.50323, -72.20552, -72.60316, -72.91813, 
-72.68677, -72.5102, -72.60832, -72.63561, -72.63599, -72.26067, 
-72.75029, -72.652511, -72.57338, -72.5798, -72.50932, -73.254, 
-73.24364, -73.10145, -73.36591, -72.60098)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Please post your data as an edit in your question, not in the comments.